Unexpected padding with a button
See this repro
jsfiddle


.test {
  width: 10rem;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.test li {
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.test li button {
  background: red;
  border: none;
}
<ul class="test">
  <li>
    <div>
      <button>
  Hello
  </button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <button>
  World
  </button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>



Why is there a padding top in each li and the button inside ?
I know it comes from the fact that we have set border: none to the button but why doesn't the li adjust to the button new height ? Why does it leave a thin space?

This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using your browser inspector.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the tour and read How to Ask and its linked resources

Paddings and list items are not what is causing the thin space. It's how the automatic height of a div is calculated when there is an inline-level children, which is based on its line-boxes height. Since the buttons have a different default font-size (at least in Chrome), the thin space appears because the background of the button only fills the smaller line box. You can see a bigger empty space by reducing the font-size or line-height. On the other hand, if you change the font-size of the button back to the initial size, the thin space will disappear as well.


.test {
  width: 10rem;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.test li {
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.test li button {
  background: red;
  border: none;
  font-size: inherit;
}
<ul class="test">
  <li>
    <div>
      <button>
          Hello
        </button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <button>
          World
        </button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>



You can see that the thin space disappears after changing the display of the buttons to display:block.


.test {
  width: 10rem;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.test li {
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.test li button {
  background: red;
  border: none;
  display: block;
}
<ul class="test">
  <li>
    <div>
      <button>
        Hello
      </button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <button>
        World
      </button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>



